# How to make coordinate plane(quadrant) graph with Highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am getting really frustrated finding out that Highchart do not have any coordinate plane graph.[image]

I have tried with Bubble chart but at some point it get complicated.

Why doesn't highchart have this simple graph?

Comment: I can only write the same as before: Something like this: jsfiddle.net/c70zfugw/8 ? Simply set `x/yAxis.min/max` options. You can calculate those values before rendering the chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to be more specific about the problem(s) you are having. But this might get you on the right path:

- Most of the charts that are produced by Highcharts use the same coordinate plane that you referring to. Everything is plotted according an `x` and a `y` coordinate.
- A `scatter` series type is the logical choice for what you are doing.
- And you need to offset your axes - you have to do a little math yourself, to determine the size of your plot area, and how far to offset them - but that's just subtracting your margins from your chart dimensions.

Look at the `offset` property of the axes:

```
xAxis: {
  offset: -175,
  ...
}
```

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.offset

Then you just plot your data as `[x,y]` pairs.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/tn5a2guc/

Comment: @jibriggs Damn, Thank you, really liked the way you have done this.

Comment: @jibriggs I have two points, A B. how would I make point A always centered? and B any of the 4 quadrant

Comment: @TanvirAlam I don't think I understand the question. A point will be centered if it's x and y values are 0. A point will be within any of the four quadrants if it has any other x and y values.